# Inserting an array into a Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, go

I want to be able to write an array of bigints into a table that I am using for history in Go. Unfortunately, I can't and when I do the error `sql: converting Exec argument #1's type: unsupported type []int64, a slice` is thrown. Here's what I'm doing, edited for brevity:

```
type Card struct {
    cid int64
}

type Transaction struct {
        tid, cardid int64
        productids []int64
        salepoint int
        cardkey string
}

func logPurchase(card *Card, t *Transaction) {
     _, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO history VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)", rand.Int63(), t.productids, card.cid, t.salepoint);
}
```

This is the structure of the table that I wish to insert into:
`tid bigint primary key, productids bigint[] not null, cardid bigint not null, salepoint int`

Comment: looks like you have an extra value in your values list.

Comment: Good catch, not sure how I managed to put that there. That issue doesn't exist within the source code where I am having this problem. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Array types are postgresql-specific.  You might need to use a library that's tailored to postgresql, such as: https://github.com/go-pg/pg

Comment: As of this writing, it doesn't appear that the `lib/pq` library currently handles array types, though there is a feature request: https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/49

Comment: Recommend updating accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41337887/2662176, after this feature was added.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implement database/sql/driver.Valuer with a custom type:

```
type int64array []int64

func (a int64array) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    // Format a in PostgreSQL's array input format {1,2,3} and return it as as string or []byte.
}
```

Comment: hi andy, cool answer. How can you implement the opposite though? Any function I need to implement to perform the psql array -> slice ?

Comment: For the reverse operation, you need to implement the `database/sql.Scanner` interface. For that you would need to use a pointer receiver.

Comment: It would be useful to add it to your answer for reference, if you want - thanks anyway!

Comment: It's already in there you just can use `pg.Int64Array` type for `productids` field

Answer (score 29):

[Arrays](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/array.go) are supported in `github.com/lib/pq` since 2016 Aug 6th. OP's statement could be written as:

```
_, err := db.Exec(
    "INSERT INTO history VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)", 
    rand.Int63(), 
    pq.Array(t.productids),   // <------- 
    card.cid, 
    t.salepoint,
)
```