# Insert string array into postgres text array field

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to make an article taggable.

Article table:

```
type Article struct {
  ID int64
  Body string
  Tags string
}
```

Preparing values:

```
tags := r.FormValue("tags")
tagArray := fmt.Sprintf("%q", strings.Split(tags, ", ")) // How do I make use of this?

t := Article{
    Body: "this is a post",
    Tags: `{"apple", "orange"}`,    // I have to hard code this for this to work.
}
if err := t.Insert(Db); err != nil {
   // Error handling
}
```

Database query:

```
func (t *Article) Insert(db *sqlx.DB) error {
    nstmt, err := db.PrepareNamed(`INSERT INTO articles
    (body, tags)
    VALUES (:body, :tags)
    RETURNING *;
    `)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer nstmt.Close()

    err = nstmt.QueryRow(t).StructScan(t)
    if err, ok := err.(*pq.Error); ok {
        return err
    }
    return err
}
```

Postgres setup for tags field:

```
tags character varying(255)[] DEFAULT '{}',
```

It seems like I have to hard code the value for tags for it to work. Otherwise I would get errors like these:

```
pq: missing dimension value
OR
pq: array value must start with "{" or dimension information
```

How do I make use of `tagArray`?

Helpful reference: https://gist.github.com/adharris/4163702

Comment: can show the exact insert script ??

Comment: you mean the database query? I have it here.

Comment: I meant the fully qualified insert statement  i.e `insert into table (col1,col2) values(1,'Some_Data')`

Comment: You mean this? `INSERT INTO articles (body, tags) VALUES (:body, :tags) RETURNING *;`

Comment: Is not `tags` of type `[]string` rather than just `string`? If you pass a `[]string` it will appear as `{"tag1", "tag2", "tag3"}` when marshalled.

Comment: I get this error: `sql: converting Exec argument #2's type: unsupported type []string, a slice`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting an array into a Postgresql database in Golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707553/inserting-an-array-into-a-postgresql-database-in-golang)

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your tags with the proper array input format, the same as your hard-coded value.

The following code will work if the tags don't contain any special characters that need to be escaped differently from how strconv.Quote would escape them:

```
tags := "apple, orange"
tagArray := strings.Split(tags, ", ")
for i, s := range tagArray {
    tagArray[i] = strconv.Quote(s)
}
final := "{" + strings.Join(tagArray, ",") + "}"
```